# reformat dimensions in excel to a standard 11 digit format

Tags: excel, format

I am struggling with some measurements which I am trying to perform calculations on. I have various sizes for example 287x60x90 or 90x600x90 and I want to reformat it to 287x060x090 etc so I can start to split out the data to 3 separate columns showing length, width, height. Have tried to format using following =text(A1,"000x000x000") and it didnt work can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks to me you're trying to solve the problem by creating another one. You should be able to split the cell contents using LEFT, MIDDLE and SEARCH. No need to reformat the cell (unless you want to reformat it for other purposes).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way using formulas:

[image: Excel sample of data]

#### Formula in B2

```
=MID(A2,1,FIND("x",A2)-1)
```

*french version*:

```
=STXT(A2;1;CHERCHE("x";A2)-1)
```

#### Formula in C2

```
=MID(A2,FIND("x",A2)+1,FIND("x",A2,FIND("x",A2,1)+1)-FIND("x",A2)-1)
```

*french version*:

```
=STXT(A2;CHERCHE("x";A2)+1;CHERCHE("x";A2;CHERCHE("x";A2;1)+1)-CHERCHE("x";A2)-1)
```

There might be a better way for this one, like using [this trick](http://excel.tips.net/T003324_Finding_the_Nth_Occurrence_of_a_Character.html) but I didn't figure it out.

#### Formula in D2

```
=MID(A2,FIND("x",A2,FIND("x",A2)+1)+1,LEN(A2))
```

*french version*:

```
=STXT(A2;CHERCHE("x";A2;CHERCHE("x";A2)+1)+1;NBCAR(A2))
```

Comment: Or write a VBA UDF which just uses `Split(cellValue,"x")`

Comment: @TimWilliams: :)... very true. I just wanted to avoid VBA

Comment: Many thanks that is starting to work a treat! I'll need to educate myself just exactly HOW its working so I can use it again in future but for now a big thanks, its a massive help to me!

Comment: @AndrewGeddes: Glad it helped. Btw, welcome to stackoverflow, if this answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information. Yet, if you need any further information on how this works, feel free to ask in the comments here or in another question (you may also try superuser.com)

Comment: @pnuts: yes. corrected the `using` typo but I don't have time to re-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in ColumnA starting A1, the simplest way may be to apply Text to Columns, Delimited, Delimiters Other (only) `x`, to a copy of ColumnA in ColumnB.

This might bypass your need for the 11 digit format but if required then in E1 and copied down to suit:

```
=TEXT(B1,"000x")&TEXT(C1,"000x")&TEXT(D1,"000")
```